# Is there a way how to add Kotlin Multiplatform target to a published KMP library which does not contain the target artifact?

Tags: kotlin, gradle, kotlin-multiplatform

I am building internal Kotlin Multiplatform (KMP) library which has a dependency to a published KMP library. The published library does not have support for the target I need, in my case it is `mingwX64` target, but that should not be important from general point of view.

The published library supports following targets: `jvm, mac/ios targets, linuxX64, android`

When I add the public library as a `commonMain` dependency to **my** `build.gradle.kts` file of **my** multiplatform internal library (which supports also `mingwX64`), the gradle is complaining, that it could not resolve the `mingwX64` artifact of the library, *as expected, because the published library doesn't support it, therefore there cannot exist published artifact for the platform.*

Is there any other way how to add the target I want to support than forking the project with missing target and adding the support for the target this way?

I would like to be able to provide a support through my internal library without touching the public library directly (without forking the source code and building the code myself), which means provide all the `expect/actual` implementations and build the code for a new targeted platform.

Comment: I don't think it's possible, but you can try creating a PR that will add your target support for the library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is not possible at the moment, but I can't find the reference to the corresponding YouTrack issue.

I guess your best bet would be to contribute the new target to the library (if it's open source).

Another option would be to write a wrapper with a similar interface and use the library as an `actual` implementation in a source set covering all its targets, and use your own custom code in a separate source set for the extra target(s).